# What is the technical meaning of dbHits?

Tags: neo4j

I am working on my master thesis and need a clear definition of `neo4js dbHits`.

On the website I only got the answer "an abstract unit of storage engine work".

Does this mean "an access to the database on the disk"?

I made some `runtime` measurements with read-only queries and also profiled the number of `dbHits`, but I always got `zero` as a result for `dbHits`.

Does that mean that all data relevant for the queries has been cached in RAM and that there is no need to access the database on the disk?

Comment: Use PROFILE, not EXPLAIN for your profile plans in order to see db hit information.

Comment: So I did, and I read the value of dbHits via the neo4j java driver functionality ProfiledPlan.dbHits().

Comment: Okay, just keep in mind that since EXPLAIN never actually executes the query that you'll always see 0 db hits there, you need to use PROFILE if you need db hit info.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details on what counts towards DBHits [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/#execution-plans-dbhits), but the idea is that it is a loose measurement of how much effort the database has to do to get the results of a query. Note that this is a measure of actual work, and not work scale.

For example, searching a Database with no indexes for a `:Person` named "Bob" would be very expensive (about 2n DBHits where n is the number of `:Person` nodes. However, if there are no nodes labeled `:Person`, the database won't do any work, because it already knows it won't find anything (0 DBHits). (So actual DBHits will very based on database contents, constraints/indexes, and even Neo4j version)

If your query took 0 DBHits to complete, that means it returned 0 results. Possible due to looking for a tag or property that doesn't exist.

Comment: The queries took 0 dbHits in any case, that was not depending on the number of results. For example, I ran queries that returned 200 results and 0 dbHits.

Comment: @Dominique Using Profile or Explain? Profile is much more accurate. Explain is a loose guess that is available if your query is too inefficient to even run. I could go into more detail if you shared a PROFILE query result though.